# IOS PJSIP integration issue

Tags: ios, pjsip

I'm trying to compile pjsip for ios .

I downloaded pjsip and made config-site.h .

On running command .configure-iphone, its fine and displays -
Done configuring for iPhoneOS8.3.sdk

But on running , make dep command , it displays following error:

```
for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build third_party/build pjmedia/build pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
    if /Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -C $dir dep; then \
        true; \
    else \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
done\
```

I don't find any solution.
Can anyone help me ?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: @buffjape i don't know how to fix that warning

Comment: lol, it doesn't look like a warning either...

Comment: @buffjape, ok then what is it ?? Will it not create problem later ?? 
any help appreciated.

Comment: I really don't know, but there's a saying "If its not broken, dont fix it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message above is a debug log, which tells that PJSIP is making a build using makefile and if the make utility can't be found in `/Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make` it simply stops executing configuration script, else the execution is not interupted.

Answer (score 0):

As azimov said, the message you posted is not an error message.  Normally, you can just run the following to finish the compiling process.

```
make dep
make
make install
```

There will be a lot of logging messages flushing your console.

People sometimes encounter problem at this step when they did no have their Xcode properly installed. I suggest to install a stand alone make executable using home-brew.

```
sudo brew install make
```